# Trying to mock method in Object gives 'AttributeError'

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-2.7, mocking

I am trying to test a method in an already existing class.  Within `inputStreamThread` method in the `Foo.crawler.crawlerapp.CrawlerApp` class the method `addUrl` is called.

`inputStreamThread` reads from stdin and then calls `addUrl`

`addUrl` is also in the `CrawlerApp` class

I was hoping to be able to use `assert_called_with` on a mock `addUrl` to check that `inputStreamThread` is doing the right thing and calling `addUrl`

Trouble is I cannot get the syntax right for the mock of `addUrl` within `CrawlerApp`

I used an example straight out of the mock docs but get the error shown below

As you can see I am also mocking stdin to be able to present test data on it

My question is, what code do I use to carry out this sort of test and not get the error shown?

```
import Foo.crawler.crawlerapp
from unittest import TestCase
from mock import patch, Mock
from mephistopheles.messageformat import EventDataFrame
from mephistopheles.messageformat.types import adservers as pbufs
import time
import sys


class testDeserial(TestCase):

    def generate_dummy_auction_event(self,url):
        adunitinfo = pbufs.AdUnitInfo(index_on_page=0, url=url)
        geoloc = pbufs.GeoLocation(country="DE", region="low")
        userinfo = pbufs.UserInfo(user_hash=1,
                                  ip_octets=1,
                                  geolocation=geoloc,
                                  language="en")
        auctioninfo = pbufs.AuctionInfo(timestamp=int(time.time()),
                                        user=userinfo,
                                        ad_unit=adunitinfo)
        return auctioninfo

    def setUp(self):
        pass

    @patch.object(Foo.crawler.crawlerapp.CrawlerApp,'addUrl')
    def test_check_url(self, MaddUrl):
        url_a = "http://audaxing.wordpress.com"
        dummy_event = self.generate_dummy_auction_event(url_a)
        with patch("sys.stdin") as mock_stdin:
            mock_stdin.read.return_value = dummy_event
            ca._running = True
            input_thread = threading.Thread(target=self.inputStreamThread)
            input_thread.start()
            time.sleep(0.5)
            ca._running = False
        MaddUrl.assert_called_with(url_a)
```

The test run output....

```
$ bin/tests --tests-pattern=test_deserialize
Test-module import failures:

Module: Foo.crawler.tests.test_deserialize

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/jamie/svn/Foo/crawler.buildout/trunk/src/Foo.crawler/Foo/crawler/tests/test_deserialize.py", line 11, in <module>
    class testDeserial(TestCase):
  File "/home/jamie/svn/Foo/crawler.buildout/trunk/src/Foo.crawler/Foo/crawler/tests/test_deserialize.py", line 28, in testDeserial
    @patch.object(Foo.crawler.crawlerapp.CrawlerApp,'addUrl')
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'object'



Test-modules with import problems:
  Foo.crawler.tests.test_deserialize
Total: 0 tests, 0 failures, 0 errors in 0.000 seconds.
```

Comment: What is the source you copied from?

Comment: @User http://docs.python.org/dev/library/unittest.mock#patch-object

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured out what to do in the end.  Bit of a monkey at a typewriter thing, not sure why I have to use "patch" and not "patch.object" or why I need to make Mock() objects first.  I just tried every possible pattern from the examples in the docs

Anyway, this works for me

```
def test_check_url(self):
    url_a = "http://audaxing.wordpress.com"
    dummy_event = self.generate_dummy_auction_event(url_a)
    with patch("sys.stdin") as mock_stdin:
        MaddUrl = Mock()
        Minit = Mock(return_value=None)
        with patch('Foo.crawler.crawlerapp.CrawlerApp.__init__', Minit, create=True):
            with patch('Foo.crawler.crawlerapp.CrawlerApp.addUrl', MaddUrl, create=True):

                ca = Foo.crawler.crawlerapp.CrawlerApp(1)
                mock_stdin.read.return_value = EventDataFrame(1, "TOKEN1", dummy_event.SerializeToString()).to_bytes()
                ca._running = True
                input_thread = threading.Thread(target=ca.inputStreamThread)
                input_thread.start()
                time.sleep(0.5)
                ca._running = False
    MaddUrl.assert_called_with(url_a)
```

Answer (score -1):

I would say the following:

```
@patch.object... #1
def test_check... #2
```

is equivalent to

```
def test_check... #2

test_check.object = ... #1
```

And one can not assign new attributes to function objects.

Comment: No, assigning new attributes to function objects is entirely possible. (Although it isn't usually a good idea.)